# Verificando existência de atalho

Tags: c#, sistema-de-arquivos

Preciso verificar a existência de um atalho, na área de trabalho do computador, porém o código abaixo não sai do `if (!File.Exists(pasta))`

```
private void Instalando()
    {
        string pasta = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\estoque Box - Gerenciamento de estoque.Lnk";
        if (!File.Exists(pasta))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(pasta);
            pnInstalando.Visible = true;
            pnInstalando.Enabled = true;
        }
        else if (File.Exists(pasta))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Olá");
            pbInstalando.Visible = false;
            pbInstalando.Enabled = false;
            pBarInstalando.Visible = false;
            pBarInstalando.Enabled = false;
            pbInstalado.Visible = true;
            btFechar.Enabled = true;
            btFechar.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

O atalho, mesmo existente no código ele acusa não existência do atalho. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Não é só você olhar a extensão do arquivo no desktop pra conferir?

Comment: A extensão .Lnk é específica  para atalhos, o caminho está OK e o arquivo está lá, não sei o que está havendo!

Comment: Eu sei. Qual é o valor de `pasta`? Digo, exatamente, qual é o valor da string? Pegue-o pelo debug, ou printe ele no console e cole aqui,

Comment: `C:\Users\Marlon Pereira\Desktop\estoque Box - Gerenciamento de estoque.Lnk`

Comment: Você tem certeza que este `.lnk` não está duplicado no nome do arquivo?

Comment: Perceba que a extensão geralmente fica oculta no Windows, então, se você está vendo um .lnk é bem provável que isso esteja duplicado.

Comment: Deu certo, agradeço!

Comment: Escolhe a resposta do jovem ali como correta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que está errado é o `.Lnk` no nome do arquivo - isto está duplicado.

Crie o atalho novamente colocando apenas "estoque Box - Gerenciamento de estoque". Dai o próprio Windows criará um .lnk.

Ou renomeie o arquivo e remova o `.Lnk`.

Daí basta usar:

> ```
> "\\estoque Box - Gerenciamento de estoque.lnk"
> ```

Comment: E como você sabe que não o arquivo já não está assim?

Comment: O link já está criado, eu devo eliminar a extensão dele? (.Lnk)

Comment: Fiz exatamente como ele, com o mesmo nome, o próprio windows adiciona um .lnk só que minusculo, então no caso ele pode simplesmente tirar o .Lnk da string, que deve funcionar.

Comment: @CassioAlves Editei sua resposta pra ficar um pouco mais clara, você pode reverter se não concordar. Apenas me avise se fizer a reversão, ok?

Comment: Tranquilo @jbueno, ficou melhor assim!